# Mixing the wine at Shevah Brachos

Tags: minhag, wedding, grapes-wine, sheva-brachos

When I'm at Shevah Brachos I've seen people pour from one cup to another or something to that effect. What is the exact procedure for mixing the cups of wine at Shevah Brachos? Is there a difference between Shabbos and Weekdays?

Comment: Note not everyone does this.

Comment: @Double AA more...  Me haber - > 1 cos; poskim (Baer  heitev)   2 cosot without. Additionally some people don't know the order of meziga

Comment: I was taught the reason was so that both bride and groom drink from both cups. How to do this is a technicality; you can use 3 cups or (rely on the alcohol to disinfect the first cup from which the _bencher_ drank and) use only 2 cups. (They usually can't both drink from the same cup because of laws of Family Purity - that would have been the simple solution.)

Answer (score 1):

See Shulchan Aruch Even Haezer 62, 9:

> יש אומרים שאין לומר ו' ברכות על כוס ברכת המזון, אלא מביא כוס אחר ואומר עליו ו' ברכות, וחוזר ולוקח כוס של ברכת המזון ואומר עליו: "בורא פרי הגפן". ויש אומרים שאין צריך, אלא על כוס של ברכת המזון מברך שבע ברכות, וכן פשט המנהג.‏
>
> הגה
>   ובמדינות אלו נוהגין כסברא הראשונה. ויש אומרים דאפלו ל"אשר ברא" לחוד בעינן שתי כוסות (מ"כ מנהגים ישנים). וברכת ארוסין וברכת חתנים אומרים אותה על שני כוסות
>
> Some poskim say that the  six blessings should not be blessed on the cup of Birkat Hamazon but they bring another  cup and one says over it six blessings. And one blesses Bore Peri Haggafen on the cup of Birkat Hamazon ...   Some Poskim are saying the cup of Birkat Hamazon alone is enough for the seven blessings. And such is the custom.
>
> RMA: In those countries the custom follows the first opinion (to use two cups) . Some Poskim are saying that "asher bara"  needs two cups, "birkat erusin"  and  "birkat chatanim"  need two cups.

I found in [this article](https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=29964) a lot of poskim. Firstly the reason for two cups is to ensure they don't   make  mitsvot by packets,  (אין עושיין מצוות חבילות)

#### and the reason of adding wine in the cup in which some one already  blessed and drank

is because the cup has become  "pagum"  and also to obtain a mixture of  to the wines of birkat Hamazon with the wine of  birkat chatanim.
1. To give wine from the pagum to the not pagum make the two pgumim.
2. So first from the not pagum to the pagum and back from it to the first. Don't mistake!

> אחרי שהוא שתה, היין שבכוסו פגום, וצריך לתקנו. ניתן לתקן אותו ע"י מזיגת יין לתוכו מתוך הכוס של שבע הברכות, ובכך מרויחים שני דברים – גם ערבוב של יין ברהמ"ז עם יין שבע הברכות, וגם תיקון הכוס הפגום.

3.Thanks to the mixture each cup contains finally wine from the  two  mitsvot.

> אח"כ צריך להחזיר מאותו כוס בחזרה לכוס של שבע הברכות כדי שגם בכוס השני תהיה תערובת של שני היינות.‏

Comment: Who needs to drink what wine? Issues of Pagum only arise once we identify who needs to drink what. Then it's just a matter of coming up with a way to divide it all right

Comment: @DoubleAA I have the same question and I'm searching.  The reported words are not  mine.  I assume that this is one issue with pagum as follows. Equality between the "quality of both cups,  but it is a loose hypothesis.  I prefer say that I don't know

Comment: presumably the bentscher should drink immediately from the cos he held for bentschin to avoid a hefseick? then he mixes as per the above. then he drinks again? then chosson and kalo? or perhaps there is no hefeseik if his das is always on drinking the mixture?

Comment: @Etzbah he can drink a bit, and then to pour from the second cup to the cup he drinked from, and afterward from this cos to the second. (not sure)